# How to add http2 request's ":path" header with tcl's http::geturl command

Tags: header, tcl, http2

I'm using tcl and I need to send http2 get request to a server. This is my code:

```
package require http
package require tls
package require json

http::register https 443 tls::socket
set url https://localhost:8001/db/get?id=25283359
set token [http::geturl $url -headers [list ":path" "/db/get?id=25283359"]]
set status [http::status $token]
set answer [http::data $token]
http::cleanup $token
http::unregister https

puts $status
puts $answer
```

and when I'm runing this code it's returns status: eof and empty body, and when I'm checking the headers of request, it is like this:

```
{host: 'localhost:8001',
'user-agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Unix; U; Linux 6.2.12) http/2.9.8  Tcl/8.6.13',
connection: 'close',
'': 'path: /db/get?id=25283359',
accept: '*/*',
'accept-encoding': 'gzip,deflate,compress'}
```

I'm also tried

```
set token [http::geturl $url -headers ["\:path" "/db/get?id=25283359"]]
```

but I'm getting same result.

Comment: Are you aware that HTTP/2 pseudo-header fields like `:path` are not HTTP header fields? See [RFC7540](https://httpwg.org/specs/rfc7540.html#rfc.section.8.1.2.1)

Comment: Use a dedicated Tcl package to handle HTTP/2 for you, e.g.: https://chiselapp.com/user/schelte/repository/www/

Comment: **The standard http package doesn't support HTTP/2** at the moment. Whether it will do so in the future is an open question, but right now you need another option.